# Angular 2 routing from joomla component

Tags: joomla, routes, angular

I'm trying to implement an angular 2 app as a joomla component, using angular2 release candidate 1. But I am having trouble getting routing to work. I think the problem have something to do with the fact that the url to the angular app is

```
localhost/index.php?=com_mycomponent
```

I have the following code:

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">   
    <!--CSS-->
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="components/com_mycomponent/app/lib/bootstrap.min.css">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="components/com_mycomponent/app/styles/styles.css">

    <!-- 1. Load libraries -->
    <!-- IE required polyfills, in this exact order -->
    <script src="components/com_mycomponent/app/lib/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="components/com_mycomponent/app/lib/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="components/com_mycomponent/app/lib/Reflect.js"></script>

    <script src="components/com_mycomponent/lib/system.src.js"></script>
    <script src="components/com_mycomponent/app/lib/system.config.js""></script>

     <script>
      System.import('components/com_mycomponent/app/scripts/bootstrapper').catch(function(err){ console.error(err); });
    </script>
    <base href="/">
</head>

<!-- 3. Display the application -->
<body>
    <body>
        <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
    </body>
</body>
</html>
```

**bootstrapper.ts**

```
import {bootstrap} from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from '@angular/router';
import {ShellComponent} from './shell.component';
import {HTTP_PROVIDERS} from '@angular/http';

bootstrap(ShellComponent, [
    HTTP_PROVIDERS,
    ROUTER_PROVIDERS
    ]);
```

**shell.component.ts**

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Routes} from '@angular/router';

import {BComponent} from 'b.component';
import {AComponent} from 'a.component';


@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'components/com_mycomponent/app/html/shell.html',
    directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

@Routes([
    {
        path: '/b',
        component: BComponent
    },
    {
        path: '/',
        component: AComponent
    }
])
export class ShellComponent{
    constructor() {
    }

    // ngOnInit() {
    //     this.router.navigate(['/egendefinertrapport']);
    // }
}
```

**shell.html**

```
<a [routerLink]="['/b']">BComponent</a>
```

And I get the following error message:

```
EXCEPTION: Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'annotations' of undefined
```

I've tried changing the bash href to '/index.php?option=com_atkstat', including the routerLink and paths - but to no avail. Any takers?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to provide a custom [RouterUrlSerializer](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterUrlSerializer-class.html) (new RC router) and a custom LocationStrategy in beta.x (RC router-deprecated) to customize which part of the URL is used or ignored by the Angular router.